# playing a single audio file on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I use this code for playing single mp3 audio file and i used MediaElement:

```
Uri Path = new Uri("AudioFiles/music.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
SoundPlayer.Source = Path;
SoundPlayer.Play();
```

but i got this error :

> > An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled  in user code
> >
> > Additional information: The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri.

what is wrong with that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the location of your file, you may need a different [Uri scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx). Try:

```
SoundPlayer.Source = new Uri(@"ms-appdata:///local/AudioFiles/music.mp3"); // if your file is in IsolatedStorage
SoundPlayer.Source = new Uri(@"ms-appx:///AudioFiles/music.mp3"); // if your file is a Build-in content
```

Note also that you don't need `SoundPlayer.Play()` if `SoundPlayer.Autoplay` is set to *true* (default setting). In case it's *false* - you will have to start to play manually in `MediaOpened` event not just after setting the `Source`.

Comment: Thank you so much . it works good . anyway which way is better for playing short sounds ? actually i am going to create an app for teaching danish language , and there are a lot of buttons in that app and when you press on them , you can listen to correct pronunciation . do you thing for this reason , mediaElement is okey or there is a better solution ?

Comment: @peymangilmour As I've understood your App will play sounds when in foreground - short ones upon button click. The MediaElement should work just fine with these cases - it will be the simplest solution and will work. The others might be to use BackgroundPlayer (IMO I wouldn't use it to play short sounds and not for foreground) and with DirectSound or SoundEffect (depending on WP version). In your case I would use MediaElement.

Comment: Thank you so much for replaying and useful information .

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri Path = new Uri("/AudioFiles/music.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
```

You are forgetting a "/" before AudioFiles.

Comment: Thanks for replaying. even if i use "/" in that code , it does not work , the solution is using right uri schema . that @romasz explained .